# Is it a good idea to inherit from dict or list classes?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiple-inheritance

Might be a nooby question, but i'm not adept in OOP of Python flavor.

I am developing test site for R&D of ML algorithms for my PhD.

I have a class that acts like an interface to CSV file containing DB.
To provide easy and uniform access to data i want to provide iterable and indexing interfaces. In general it would be great if my class would act as dictionary, cause it would be representative of underlying data.

So, as i see it, there are two options for me:

1. Define all methods of dictionary that i need, that define the rest of method, while closely looking in to python dict() reference. And then hope that it all works and i have all the functionality i need. In this way i would have "private" dictionary in my class that contains all my data.

or

2. I use dict and a super class for my CSV-reader and reinterpret methods of creating and expanding dictionary. So in general in would create dictionary of objects stored in CSV, and class provides some additional functionality(like verification and custom access)

I would like to hear your thought on the matter and if possible some links on "correct" way on developing classes that use wide array of language supplied methods in Python.

Comment: Third option: inherit from `collections.abc.Mapping` and implement the abstract methods defined for that class.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes, you only need to provide `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__` methods. If you want to support mutating the data, use the `MutableMapping` subclass instead and add the `__setitem__` and  `_delitem__` implementations.